# Iterating through a pyparsing tree yields only unique items?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a simple parser written in pyparsing below:

```
import pyparsing as pp

Token = pp.Word(pp.alphas)("Token")
Modifier = pp.Word(pp.nums)("Modifier")

Random = pp.Group(pp.Keyword("?") + pp.OneOrMore(Modifier))("Random")
Phrase = pp.Group(Token + pp.OneOrMore(Modifier))("Phrase")

Collection = pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(Phrase ^ Random, ","))("Collection")

tree = Collection.parseString("hello 12 2, ? 1 2, word 4, ? 3 4, testing 5")
```

I then tried doing this:

```
>>> for name, item in tree[0].items():
        print name, item
Phrase ['testing', '5']
Random ['?', '3', '4']
```

...but for some reason, it returned only the last `Phrase` and `Random` items in the tree.  How can I get all of them?

(Note: I also tried doing this:

```
>>> for item in tree[0]:
        print item
['hello', '12', '2']
['?', '1', '2']
['word', '4']
['?', '3', '4']
['testing', '5']
```

...but as you can see, it doesn't return the token name, which I need.  I also tried doing `item.name`, but those always returned empty strings.)

**How do I iterate through a pyparsing tree and get every single item, in order, along with the assigned name?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ParseResults can get their defining name by calling `getName()`:

```
>>> for f in tree[0]: print f.getName(), f.asList()
... 
Phrase ['hello', '12', '2']
Random ['?', '1', '2']
Phrase ['word', '4']
Random ['?', '3', '4']
Phrase ['testing', '5']
```

You can also revert to using `setResultsName` and setting the `listAllMatches` argument to True. In version 1.5.6, the `expr("name")` shortcut was enhanced so that if the name ends with '*', then that is equivalent to `expr.setResultsName("name", listAllMatches=True)`. Here is how the output changes by setting this flag:

```
>>> Random = pp.Group(pp.Keyword("?") + pp.OneOrMore(Modifier))("Random*")
>>> Phrase = pp.Group(Token + pp.OneOrMore(Modifier))("Phrase*")
>>> Collection = pp.Group(pp.delimitedList(Phrase ^ Random, ","))("Collection")
>>> tree = Collection.parseString("hello 12 2, ? 1 2, word 4, ? 3 4, testing 5")
>>> print tree.dump()
[[['hello', '12', '2'], ['?', '1', '2'], ['word', '4'], ['?', '3', '4'], ['testing', '5']]]
- Collection: [['hello', '12', '2'], ['?', '1', '2'], ['word', '4'], ['?', '3', '4'], ['testing', '5']]
  - Phrase: [['hello', '12', '2'], ['word', '4'], ['testing', '5']]
  - Random: [['?', '1', '2'], ['?', '3', '4']]
```